# Nextjs Build size is GROWING

Tags: next.js

A new nextjs project (built on app routes), when I do `npm run build` the **.next** folder is around 32mb.

Is this a normal size for a nextjs project? As I started development resulting the .next folder to get upto 90mbs! (out of which 85mb is consumed by the cache folder)

The development is still on going and I am assuming this size would increase, few insights would be helpful !

(FYI - first load js are less than 100kb for all routes)

Tried output: 'export' in next.config. The out folder was generated with less mb size but how does this folder should be used

Answer (score 1):

In the .next folder, there is a folder called ***cache***  .there is no need for it. You can delete it